# how to set start page in backend magento for different role user in magento

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

suppose in magento backend i have to 2 role one is admin, other is sales. just like admin set start page for admin is dashboard. I want to set sales order is to be start page for sales role user.i want to know is there is any way to assign a start page for different role in magento.

Comment: if login as a sales order tab only displayed right. your question is not clear

Comment: supoose If login by  sales team (role) his start page is manage product page in magento  backend. This is i want to know.

Comment: I think dynamically we can't change but we can restrict permission

Comment: I am taking about how can set or customize start page for different role user not about resource access.@LearningMagento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native function too achieve this.

> But you can use `admin_session_user_login_success` event for this.

To implement magento event observer refer this [link](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/)

then add event in your config.xml file

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <admin_session_user_login_success>
            <observers>
                <some_unique_handle>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class> 
                    <method>adminRedirect</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </some_unique_handle>
            </observers>
        </admin_session_user_login_success>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then add this code in you observer file.

i.e., 
**Path :** app/code/{your-codepool}/{namespace}/{module}/Model/Observer.php

```
public function adminRedirect($observer)
{
    //get admin user id from observer
    $currentUserId = $observer->getuser()->getId();
    //get User Role
    $userRole = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($currentUserId)->getRole()->getRoleName();
    if($userRole == 'sales'){
             // If user role is sales then it'll redirect to the sales order list page
        $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
        $response->clearHeaders()
                        ->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order'))
                        ->sendHeadersAndExit();
    }
    return $this;
}
```