# Redirect admin user to system configuration in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, third-party-module

I don't know is it possible or not.

I want to redirect user to system configuration when user logged in to admin.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think something like this was already asked here: [how to set start page in backend magento for different role user in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84002/how-to-set-start-page-in-backend-magento-for-different-role-user-in-magento).

You just have to change `adminRedirect()` mehtod to fit for your needs, like adjust `getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order')` to `getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/yor_tab')`. Since you have no check for user role this should be enough for `Observer.php`:

```
$response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
$response->clearHeaders()
    ->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config'))
    ->sendHeadersAndExit();
```

---

**Answer from linked question:**

There is no native function too achive this.

> But you can use `admin_session_user_login_success` event for this.

To implement magento event observer refer this [link](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/)

then add event in your config.xml file

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <admin_session_user_login_success>
            <observers>
                <some_unique_handle>
                    <class>[your_model]/observer</class> 
                    <method>adminRedirect</method>
                </some_unique_handle>
            </observers>
        </admin_session_user_login_success>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then add this code in you observer file.

i.e., 
**Path :** app/code/{your-codepool}/{namespace}/{module}/Model/Observer.php

```
public function adminRedirect($observer)
{
    //get admin user id from observer
    $currentUserId = $observer->getuser()->getId();
    //get User Role
    $userRole = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($currentUserId)->getRole()->getRoleName();
    if ($userRole == 'sales') {
             // If user role is sales then it'll redirect to the sales order list page
        $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
        $response->clearHeaders()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order'))
            ->sendHeadersAndExit();
    }
    return $this;
}
```