# How to add custom config in custom module to role user admin in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, user-roles, role

I created a module and use it in the config, but when set role user, it does not show, please help me!

Comment: You can get some help from this reference link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84002/how-to-set-start-page-in-backend-magento-for-different-role-user-in-magento